# FileManager for TinyMCE on Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I have successfully installed TinyMCE and the FileManager plugin

`https://github.com/2b3ez/FileManager4TinyMCE`

and I am just having some issues getting to my `public/img` folder from the FileManager source code located in `public/js/rte/plugins/filemanager`. I always use blade for my paths so I am not sure how I can configure the `config.php`

```
$base_url="http://localhost"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = '/tinymce/source/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../../../source/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload files folder
```

The above snip is what I need to use in order to point to my img folder. Would it be best just create an img folder inside of the bath and just work from that? I would prefer to just work out of the `public/img` for all my images

Comment: Shouldn't $current_path be  '../../../../tinymce/source/';  ? I really don't get what is the question here, You're asking for opinions on folder structure?

Comment: @Lynx: Hi... can you please tell me at which folder you have uploaded the filemanager4tinymce in laravel? is it in app/includes? and did your issue solved? please tell me..because i'm now facing the same problem.

Comment: @Ammu I believe I put everything in /public.

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_url="http://localhost"; //url base of site if you want only relative url leave empty
$upload_dir = '/img/'; // path from base_url to upload base dir
$current_path = '../../../../img/'; // relative path from filemanager folder to upload    files folder
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, a good answer contains not just a blob of code, but an explanation of what the code does and why it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the file-manager folder inside the public folder and created a folder in it called uploads and it seems to work perfectly that way.

```
$base_url     = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];  // DON'T TOUCH (base url 
                                                    // (only domain) of site 
                                                    // (without final "/")).

$upload_dir   = '/local_search/public/uploads/';    // path from base_url to base
                                                    // of upload folder (with 
                                                    // start and final "/")

$current_path = '../uploads/';                      // relative path from 
                                                    // filemanager folder to 
                                                    // upload folder (with final 
                                                    // "/")
```

Comment: But then your uploaded files would not be protected

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I'd change my `$upload_dir` to **private**:

```
$upload_dir   = '/local_search/PRIVATE/uploads/';    // path from base_url to base
                                                     // of upload folder (with 
                                                     // start and final "/")
```

And then create an `Assets`- or `File_Controller` to access these files.

If security is not an issue however, your current solution should work just fine.

Comment: Only thing that will be uploaded is text and images. All of that would be going to a database. Is that something I should protect? I am not sure how much can be accessed from that